# How to Load SQL Geometry Data on OpenLayers3?

Tags: javascript, sql, openlayers

I am New in OpenLayers 3. I have to load Geometry data from sql to my OpenLayers map.

This is my code :

```
var tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'osm' })
})

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: vectorSource,
style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#0099FF'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#0033CC',
        width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#0099FF'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#0033CC',
            width: 2
            })
        })
    }),
});

map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',  // The DOM element that will contains the map
renderer: 'canvas', // Force the renderer to be used
layers: [tileLayer, vectorLayer],
overlays: [overlay],
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([2, 41], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 3
    })
});
```

This my code for a OpenLayers3 map.
I have data with geometry field in my table. So, i want to draw on my openlayers map with this geometry fied.

This is Data in my geometry Field.
0xE6100000010CDDB5847CD0FF56C00EBE30992A583D40

so, how can i draw with this type of data?